# Is there a way to search text string (not keywords) from 1 cell into another cell and loop through entire dataset?

Tags: r

I'm trying to conduct a text string search based on 1 column value (1st data frame) if it partially or fully matches with another column (in 2nd data frame) (not via keywords). Both datasets are different in size.  (Using R 3.5.1)

Working on 2 datasets which are 900K and 80 K observations each. First dataset has column that contains a product code (prod_code: ABC-1562) and the second one has column containing Family_code (family_code: ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892). Both tables has a product identification number (prod id: 4772345) assigned to each unique product code.

I tried using charmatch, match, string_detect but so far I couldn't make any head with my code.

## Using match

```
df2<- df2%>% mutate_(check = match(df1$prod_code, df2$family_code)
```

## Using charmatch

```
df1$char_match <- charmatch(df1$prod_code, df2$family_code)
```

## Using str_detect

```
df1%>% mutate (String_check = str_detect(df2$family_code, df1$prod_code))
```

## Expected Result

I need to query: 
1. If the value from 1st column (Product code) exists in 2nd column (Family Code)
2. Store the output in column if Product code exists in string of Family

code.

## product_code  (1st Dataset)

Obs 1- ABC-1562
Obs n- ABC-1562

## family_code  (2nd Dataset)

Obs 1- ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892
Obs n- ABC-1563; ABC-1564; ABC-9892

## QC (Match Result)

Obs 1- TRUE
Obs n- FALSE

QC can either be Boolean or numeric, both cases will suffice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `grepl`

```
df=data.frame(a=c("ABC-1562","ABC-1562"),
              b=c("ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892","ABC-1563; ABC-1564; ABC-9892"),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(res=if_else(grepl(a,b),TRUE,FALSE))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a        b                            res  
  <chr>    <chr>                        <lgl>
1 ABC-1562 ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892 TRUE 
2 ABC-1563 ABC-1563; ABC-1564; ABC-9892 FALSE
```

**EDIT**

From what I understand, you have two df such as:

```
> df1=data.frame(id=c(3,2,5),prod_code=c("ABC-1562","ABC-1562","ABC-1563"),
+                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df1
  id prod_code
1  3  ABC-1562
2  2  ABC-1562
3  5  ABC-1563

> df2=data.frame(id=c(5,2,1),family_code=c("ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892","ABC-1563; ABC-1564; ABC-9892",
+                                          "ABC-1561; ABC-1564; ABC-989"),
+                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df2
  id                  family_code
1  5 ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892
2  2 ABC-1563; ABC-1564; ABC-9892
3  1  ABC-1561; ABC-1564; ABC-989
```

We can do a `left_join` to match `prod` and `family` by `id`. Then use `ifelse` with the same condition as before to see if there is a match.

```
> df=left_join(df1,df2,by="id")%>%rowwise()%>%
+   mutate(res=if_else(grepl(prod_code,family_code),
+                      TRUE,FALSE))
> df
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id prod_code family_code                  res  
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                        <lgl>
1     3 ABC-1562  NA                           FALSE
2     2 ABC-1562  ABC-1563; ABC-1564; ABC-9892 FALSE
3     5 ABC-1563  ABC-1563; ABC-1562; ABC-9892 TRUE
```

This way you can also see if there is any `id` with no match

Comment: thanks for your reply! Instead of mentioning the values I provided the column name and it revert backs the error:   "arguments imply differing number of rows:" Reason I am trying with column name is because this is large dataset and I can't populate the code with unique values for a and b. Appreciate if you can provide further feedback.

Comment: Hello! looking at the last lines of your question, I got the wrong idea that you were comparing the two values rowwise from `1` to `n`. If thats not the case, I don't think I fully understand your question. Would you return `TRUE` if a product_code observation is similar to any row of family_code? maybe give a more clear expected result

Comment: Thanks @boski for digging into question, I updated my problem description now. So both datasets have a common field i.e. "prod id" (a unique 'product id' for unique 'product code'). So the methodology in my head is, match the row based on "prod id" and then compare "prod_code" from data set 1 to "family_code" in data set 2. Thanks!

Comment: @HImanshuThakur forgot to mention I updated with (hopefully) adequate response